# How can increase border height between two DIVs when any DIV height increases?

Tags: css, html

I'm having a problem with DIV height. see the picture, there are 2 div tags and div-1 has right border with black color. and div-1 and div-2 height is not set.I want that any of those div height when increases with content then the border between two div tags will increase automatically and always will be like the picture.if I used table then it wasn't that problem. but using div tags how can this possible ?

[image]

-Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care for IE7 you can use `display: table-cell` to get your layout straight. It will force both elements to have the very same height so the border will always hit your black bottom.

```
div.page {
    display: table;
    width: 500px;
}
div.page > section {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 70%;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div.page > aside {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
    <section>Left</section>
    <aside>Left</aside>
</div>
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/VEzUG/

You can of course use `<div>`s instead of `<section>` and `<aside>`.

Comment: that worked.thanks for your answer, yes I used div id="section" and aside too. the problem is internet explorer, but may be it can't be solved if think about IE.

Comment: Glad I could help. If I got your comment right: If you want to use HTML5 elements in IE8 you can use [html5shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/).